# What are the chances my visa will get accepted

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, syrian-citizens

I'm a 15 year old syrian travelling to Greece with my mother and 2 sisters who are younger than me, we have booked in Athens  for one month and also flight tickets prior to applying, we're arriving there with 30,000€, we've submitted the employment details and travel insurance, what are the odds we'll get rejected? , we traveled to Europe under a schengen visa in 2016 before

Comment: We can’t predict the odds, but having previously had a visa counts in your favour unless your family’s circumstances have changed significantly since 2016.

Comment: Are you planning to carry €30,000 in cash? If so you must declare it on arrival in Greece (and possibly on departure from Syria). Expect to be questioned on the provenance of such a large sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot tell you the odds. But some things would appear alarming to a visa official unless your explanation was unclear.

- *Bringing* €30000 for one month would be rather unusual. Few tourists spend that much. *Having* that much money at home and bringing only a small part is better.
- A stable job with income in excess of expenses is much more important than the money at hand.

Comment: I think carrying that amount of cash, even if planning to spend less, would itself be a red flag for a visa officer.

Comment: @David, edited.